# Array in Javascript (array.forEach Vs array.map)

Tags: javascript

Please I have a very simple question. What is the different between the array.forEach and  array.map.
I am confuse because they both run a function on each element of an array.

If they are the same why did they introduce the map function in ES6.
If they are not where should map be used ahead of forEach.

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined` where as `map` returns a new array.

Comment: `array#map` returns an array while `array#forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `.map()` was introduced at the same time as `.forEach()`. Are you confusing it with `Map` from ES6?